# Visualforce Page and Visual Flow - Back and forth redirection - Solution?

Tags: visual-workflow, visualforce, flow, redirect

I have a visual flow that is started on a click of Custom button.  This flow is embedded in a visualforce page (standard way of using flows).

Now, in one of the steps in the flow, I want to redirect the user to a New Visualforce page (this page has the functionality of File Upload).  In this page, the user will upload file (creates a uppload record).  Then can the user be redirected back to THAT step in the flow where he left and continue with the remaning steps in the flow?

What is the feasible solution for this requirement.

So, in short, it is something like below.

Flow step1 ==> flow step 2 ==> Visualforce Page(upload file) ==> flow step 3 ==> finish flow.

EDIT:  All this can be solved, if there is File Upload option in flow! #JustAThought

Comment: Couldn't you just rerender a panel on the vf page to show at the point in the flow you want it to? Your flow would need to set a variable to tell your page controller when to display and undisplay the panel. I'm sure I've done something like this before but can't find the example at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can redirect like this:

```
<flow:interview name="CrossSell" interview="{!theInterview}" finishLocation="{!finishLocation}">
public PageReference getfinishLocation() {
    return new PageReference('/apex/some-fileuploadpage');
}
```

after upload, as a work around,  you can start another flow instead.

Comment: but cannot come back to the same flow where we left it?

Comment: it can not go back, but can restart the same flow, in this case you need add checking at the start of your flow, if not file upload, go to step1, if file uploaded, go to step3.